# Pairing the "Learning Curve" font

Tags: website-design, fonts, font-recommendation, critique, font-pairing

I'm trying to find a good pairing for the [Learning Curve](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/learning-curve-pro) font, to use in a website. This particular font is used in the client's logo.

I must convey a stylish and elegant mood, and I've tried to pair it with [Josefin Sans](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/josefin-sans):

> [image]

Is my choice a good one? Is this pairing right to convey the mood that I described? Can it be improved in some way?

Comment: Thank you for this simple yet perfect example of a good Critique question!

Answer (score 2):

<sub><sup>Disclaimer: I am not a fan of 'school' handwritings, so my negative opinion on Learning Curve may sound through in this post.</sup></sub>

Let's start out with the observation that Learning Curve is not a very elegant typeface. To me, it very much evokes a schoolclass feel: it's the script I (and lots of my generation) were taught to write in. That means that we have to have the second typeface be unambiguously elegant and stylish. Also, it needs to be easy on the eyes and attract little attention, as Learning Curve already is very busy, taking up mindspace.

In order to still get a stylish and elegant vibe off of this, my first impulse would be to choose a typeface as elegant and stylish as possible for a body text: a classic serif. That said, shy away from defaults like Times New Roman. (Shy away from Times New Roman, period, but that's another story.) Options would be Palatino, Garamond or even Georgia.

I'm rather surprised by your choice for a geometric sans: although those are Art-Deco and Bauhaus, they aren't the greatest typefaces for body text. There are exceptions, but usually they are too busy and 'present' to function as body type. My rule of thumb is to always use a classic serif or a subdued sans as body font. They are legible, clear, and relatively invisible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; like I said, the choice for "Learing Curve" was already made, I am tasked with the creation of the website, not with a rebranding. I will try some more combinations based on your suggestions.

Comment: I understood the restriction for the script. My first paragraph was just to illustrate that you have some compensation to do in the choice of the other typeface. I'll clarify the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. To answer you: my initial try with Josefin instead of a more classic option was because I also need  a type that could be used also for menu items, smaller headings and all other cases (even with smaller text than major headings) where Learning Curve, simply, wont' be readable. And I was trying to avoid mixing three typefaces. Anyway, I'm experimenting different combinations.

Comment: Mixing three typefaces is always a bad idea, so great thinking there. Do remember that you can always use a classic serif in small caps for menu items and headings--it tends to look quite spiffy and chique!